# Git: How to checkout newly created remote branch?

Tags: git

A new minor version branch for Drupal 8 is created every 6 months but the default branch remains the previous one. For example, right now the default branch is [8.6.x](https://www.drupal.org/node/3060/git-instructions) and the latest branch is 8.7.x.

```
git clone --depth 1 git@git.drupal.org:project/drupal.git
```

The above command clones the default branch i.e. 8.6.x but I want to clone the newly created remote branch i.e. 8.7.x

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch $NEWEST_BRANCH git@git.drupal.org:project/drupal.git
```

Is there a way to dynamically set the `NEWEST_BRANCH` to the newly created remote branch?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to dynamically set the `NEWEST_BRANCH` to the newly created remote branch?

Not within Git itself, no—there's no notion of "newly created".  Moreover, while some may use [some variant of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning#Sequence-based_identifiers) [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/), not everyone does (and there are [valid arguments against the concept in the first place](https://gist.github.com/jashkenas/cbd2b088e20279ae2c8e)).  Essentially, it's hard even to know what "newest" *means*.

(Side note: the phrase "remote branch" is not a very good one either, if only because Git muddies the waters by having local entities that are often called "remote branches" in lieu of the more-accurate *remote-tracking branch names*, or my preferred phrase, *remote-tracking names*.  In this case you just mean "latest" or "newest" *on* the specified other-Git-repository.)

What I might suggest for this particular issue is using either of the following:

1. Run `git ls-remote`, and use that to select a particular branch.  You can then use `git clone -b <name> --depth 1`.
2. Run `git clone --depth 1 --no-single-branch`: you will get many depth-1 remote-tracking names, one for each branch on the remote.  You can then peruse them and `git checkout` whichever one you prefer.

Method 1 is more labor-intensive, but I timed cloning 8.6.x (about 10 seconds real time for this particular test) vs `--no-single-branch` (about 30 seconds real time) so you might prefer it for some sort of automated thing.